# Ionic 2 Admob Plugin cordova-plugin-admob-free

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I have tried to use this plugin in Ionic 2 as shown [there](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/)  and add inside of src/app/app.components.ts ;

```
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(private admobFree: AdMobFree,platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();


      const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
         id: 'ca-app-pub-MYCODE',
         isTesting: true,
         autoShow: true
        };
      this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
      this.admobFree.banner.show();  


    });
  }
}
```

like that code.

Also I import module,add provider to src/app/app.module.ts ;

```
import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AdMobFree,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And when I try in emulator application work fine but ads not coming. Am I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
constructor(private admobFree: AdMobFree) {
this.showBannerAd(); //calling banner ads
} 

async showBannerAd(){

try{
  const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
    id : 'ca-app-pub-xxxx',
    isTesting : true,
    autoShow : true
  }
  this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
  const result = await this.admobFree.banner.prepare();
  console.log('ad works fine', result);

}

catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}
}
```